# No video output on newly built PC

Tags: graphics-card, hardware-failure, hardware-detection

Building a computer from scratch.  Attached everything and it doesn't output to the monitor.

The VGA led error light on the motherboard lights up even when it's only the RAM CPU and CPU cooler connected.

When the ram is removed the RAM LED warning light goes on but the VGA light goes off. Switch individual RAM chips between the slots and its the same VGA LED on.

> Processor i7 7700
>   RAM x2 crucial 8gb DDR4-2133 (1.2v)
>   PSU Silverstone sst-st45sf (450w)
>   Case Silverstone SG05
>   Motherboard ASUS B150i pro gaming aura
>   Graphics card 1050 Gigabyte (gv-n1050-2gd)

Can somebody please assist?

Comment: Those graphics cards usually need additional power. Have you connected everything?

Comment: a 450w power supply probably won't be powerful enough - Do you see anything when unplugging the 1050 and using the built in video?

Comment: @MichaelBay - It was without the 1050

JonnyVegas - It doesn't need any extra power.  It is currently running more with the same power supply.  So just the CPU fan and RAM gives the VGA light error.

Comment: How old is your PSU?  There's a chance one of the rails is under powering things, causing the fault.  This could be due to age or it just doesn't have the total amps on one of the rails to power everything.  I've been using https://outervision.com to calculate power requirements lately.

Comment: Also, double check to make sure the GPU is fully seated.  It's easy to think those are in when they aren't.

Comment: The parts are all brand new and the GPU is seated properly.